# What does $f(x)=\lim_{\ell \to \infty} \ell\sin(\frac{x}{\ell})-\sum_{n=1}^{\ell-1}\frac{n\sin(\frac{x}{n})}{\ell-1}$ converge to, if at all?

Tags: limits, trigonometric-series

I was messing around on Desmos when I came across this function involving a limit:

$$f(x)=\lim_{\ell \to \infty} \ell\sin\left(\frac{x}{\ell}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{\ell-1}\frac{n\sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)}{\ell-1}$$

that I couldn't find the answer to.

I graphed an approximation on Desmos and it seemed to approach a sinusoid with amplitude L. Could anyone help me simplify it further? Thanks in advance.

(I'm in Calculus I so if the answer involves something higher-level than that please state it beforehand.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Stolz-Cesaro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\ell\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\ell-1}n\sin(x/n)}{\ell-1}&=\lim_{\ell\to\infty}\ell \sin(x/\ell)\\\\
&=x
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the limit of interest is $0$

Comment: I don't understand how you can derive the second expression from the first one. I haven't used or learned the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem yet, and the Wikipedia article is not that clear. Could you elaborate on how the theorem can be used to derive the second expression?

Comment: Let $a_\ell=\sum_{n=1}^{\ell-1} n\sin(x/n)$ and $b_\ell =\ell-1$.  Then surely $a_{\ell+1} -a_{\ell}=\ell \sin(x/\ell)$ and $b_{\ell+1} -b_{\ell}=1$.  Now the limit of the ratio $\frac{a_{\ell+1}-a_\ell}{b_{\ell+1}-b_\ell}=\ell\sin(x/\ell)$ is $x$.  I hope that this is clear now.

Comment: That makes much more sense, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.